# Set the title for the navigation control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I converted window based application into navigation based but I am not able to set the title for the navigation bar.

```
controller = [[bookDisplayViewController alloc] initAndCreateView];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
nav.title=@"Application";
[window addSubview:nav.view];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible for you to place

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"YourName";
```

in the viewDidLoad of the other view? I'd try it that way and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the title from within the UIViewController. Try this:

```
controller.navigationItem.title=@"Application";
```

Infact apple docs on UINavigationItem for the "title" property  states that:

```
title
A localized string that represents the view that this controller manages.

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title
Discussion
Subclasses should set the title to a human-readable string that represents the view to the user. If the receiver is a navigation controller, the default value is the top view controller’s title.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
```